# Constructing an equilateral triangle using Tarski's axioms for geometry

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In Euclid's first geometry proposition, he constructs an equilateral triangle given an arbitrary line segment. I was wondering if it was possible to prove this straight from Tarski's axioms for geometry (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms). This amounts to proving the following statement:

Given points $a,b$ prove that there exists a point $x$ such that $ax\equiv ab$ and $bx\equiv ab$.

Euclid's reasoning behind this is that the two circles centered at $a$ and $b$ with radius $ab$ "obviously" intersect. More generally we could ask whether we could formally prove if any two circles that "obviously" intersect at two points actually do so, given by the following statement:

Given points $a,b,c,d$ such that $Babc$ and $Bbcd$ prove that there exists a point $x$ such that $ax\equiv ac$ and $dx\equiv db$.

I am not really sure on how to get a nontrivial point (meaning not some arbitrary point) outside of the line that $a,b,c,d$ lie in.

Comment: I'm a bit confused – why do you need four points to start with? If you are given a line segment, would not it be specified by two points $a,b$? If given $a,b$, I guess Lower Dimension gives you a third point $c$ not collinear with them, and Segment Construction assures you can extend the line $ac$ to a new line $az$ with the same length as $ab$.

Comment: Oh well: Lower Dimension just gives *some* three noncollinear points. I guess you need some more gymnastics to get a point noncollinear with the *given* two points $a,b$.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Once you have three noncollinear points, they can't all be on the line through $a,b$.  So one of them will be what you want.  Also, it seems there are four points in the question because, despite "equilateral", the OP is really looking for a triangle with arbitrary prescribed sides, not necessarily all equal.

Comment: I edited the statement so that it is perhaps less confusing. The statement is pretty much equivalent to what @AndreasBlass states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to construct an equilateral triangle on $p$ and $q$ using Tarski's axioms -- i.e. combining the existential axioms to get the vertex of such a triangle, omitting the proof by the other axioms that this works.

Let $vw\ge xy$ abbreviate $\exists z(Bxyz \wedge vw = xz)$.

[image]

By Lower Dimension, there are $a,b,c$ which are not collinear. Assume without loss of generality that $c$ is not on the line between $p$ and $q$, and that $cp \ge cq$.

By Continuity, choose $m$ with $Bpmq$ and $mp=mq$.

By Continuity, choose $d$ with $Bcdp$ and $dp=dq$.

By Segment Construction, choose $e$ with $Bmde$ and $de=pq$.

By Continuity, choose $t$ with $Bmte$ and $pt=pq$.

For all these uses of Continuity, the axiom actually requires a pair of inequalities rather than an equality. So for the last line, we can let $\phi(x) = Bmxe \wedge px \le pq$, and $\psi(y)=Bmye \wedge py \ge pq$, and use the continuity axiom in the form
$$\forall x\, \forall y\,[(\phi(x) \wedge \psi(y)) \to Bmxy]\, \to\, \exists t\, \forall x\, \forall y\,[(\phi(x) \wedge \psi(y)) \to Bxty]$$
The other uses of the continuity axiom are similar.

Comment: Is the continuity necessary for a construction of an equilateral triangle? Can it be constructed without the axiom of continuity and without parallels? Because what you are actually using is called Circle-Segment Continuity, which is one of the weakest forms of the Axioms of Continuity. A bit stronger is Circle-Circle Continuity, which allows to produce all familiar straightedge-and-compass constructions.